# Как получать из [[123], [456], [123, 4, 5, 6]] ->[123, 456, 123, 4, 5, 6]?

Tags: python

Как получать из

`[[123], [456], [123, 4, 5, 6]]` **--->** `[123, 456, 123, 4, 5, 6]`?

Comment: Могут ли встречаться обыкновенные числа (не в списке) или вложенные списки в исходных данных? Например, так: `[123, [1, 2, 3], [4, [5, 6], 7], 8]`

Comment: @Стас нет, таких быть не может, но если Вы знаете как и [123, [1, 2, 3], [4, [5, 6], 7], 8] преобразовывать, то напишите пожалуйста

Comment: я закрыл вопрос в виду вашей лени поискать уже имеющиеся ответы.